# Oracle and Java: oracle/sql/ARRAY cannot be resolved

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using oracle 11g and trying to load java project with loadjava utility. I have 2 different schema. loadjava to schema1 executes successfuly, but at the same time to schema2 it not loads **oracle/sql/ARRAY** class with error that it could not be resolved. When i trying to create java stored procedure and use that class in this procedure, compilation fails with error:

```
bad class file: null class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
```

I know what it means. But my project compiles with 1.5 jdk and Oracle DB has java version 1.5_10. (keep in mind, that in different schema that project uploads fine and same stored procedure works correctly). And i have ojdbc5.jar in my classpath(Maven). Any suggestions? I spend 2 days to resolve that, but I'm still at this point.

Comment: schema2 have possibly not the required rights. take a look at the privileges differences of schema1 and schema2

Comment: is this already existing in schema1?  will loadjava -resolve work on schema1?

Answer (score 0):

Well version 50.0 means it's a Java 1.6 class file.  So somewhere along the way you are using a class file that is too new.  If I were you, I'd extract all of the jar files you are using in the project to a temporary directory and then figure out which class file is wrong.

On unix/linux, you could do that like this:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
for i in `ls whereever_your_jar_files_are/*.jar`
do
  jar xf $i
done
find . -name '*.class' -exec file {} \; | grep 50.0
```

That will give you some clue as to which library is providing the newer versioned class file.